# How can I prevent pinned tabs in Chromium from being accidentally closed?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

In Firefox, when you're in a pinned tab, you cannot close the tab using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. However, you *can* in Chrome/Chromium. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why would you ever "accidentally" hit CTRL+W in the first place..?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Sometimes I have too many tabs open and want to close them all. I realize that this is an edge case, but it'd be nice to have either way

Comment: Do you know that you can quickly close a tab by clicking on it with the mouse wheel? It's very useful in such situations, I do it every day: quickly middle-click all tabs from right to left and they all close in a second.